# How can we share android project that is connect with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have build an android application in my laptop using android studio. The project is connected with firebase using two features i.e. Authentication and Realtime Database. I want to share the project to my group but I can only share the android project, the firebase doesn't get share. Can we share the whole project including the Firebase also?

I tried creating new Firebase project and registering the app but it didn't work.
I also tried to remove the firebase connection and connecting again to new project.
I also entered SHA1 again to new project.

Comment: What do you mean by "share the whole project including the Firebase"? Are you referring to the data in the Firebase Console?